# Application Install in Compatibility Mode

Tags: compatibility

Could anyone please tell me how I can install an application in Compatibility Mode? I am getting restrictions so that I can not install any single application. Waiting for solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 then It is easy to install any application in compatibility mode. Simply check [this post](https://www.techprefer.com/how-to-install-an-application-in-compatibility-mode-in-windows-10/). It has step by step solution of installing application in compatibility mode.